Which directories remain private whilst running a Vue.js application on Hapi?
I've been using Hapi.js to run my API server for a few years and I have been very pleased with simplicity and peformance.  In order to reduce complexity I am considering moving my Vue.js application off Nginx and over to my Hapi server as well. It will also reduce the number of Docker images I need to maintain.
I assume I would just deploy my /dist folder over to /public but I know that with Vite the directory structure has changed from what vue cli created and some stuff which used to be public no longer is.  Unfortunately, I am not finding any docs which address this directly.

"I know that with Vite the directory structure has changed from what vue cli created and some stuff which used to be public no longer is" - can you clarify what are your concerns? Is it vite or vue cli that you are using? Any way, in both cases the build results in all files to be in dist/

Great question.  I have been digging through my notes and beginning to wonder if I was imaging that.  I know styles.ccc was move to /src but I am not finding what I was looking for.   My concerns were publishing any files which should not be made public but that is really more for full-on web servers like Apache and Nginx - which I am moving away from.   If you want to make that into an answer I will accept it.

I am using Vite btw
